# Linkedin How to get email addresses of connections

Tags: php, linkedin-api, invite

I am adding 'Invite a Friend' on my website, for that I have planned to included email grabber. I have tried http://openinviter.com/demo/ but you can see its not working for Linkedin, its mentioned on that demo page too.

How can I grab Email Addresses of LinkedIn Connections ? Preferably in PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For connections, you can only grab the most [basic profile fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile), which does not include email address:

> For 1st and 2nd degree connections, you may only retrieve profile fields available with the r_basicprofile member permission

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

Comment: It is now possible to get the email field. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment nothin' changed about connections. Only basic profile fields available for connections.
I think it is logical that if current member must confirm access to his email **separately** from his profile fields - the emails of his connections are not confirmed by those members, so they cannot be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

LInkedin doesn't provide email address

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn has started the email address for the new Apps, but still can't use it for your existing LinkedIn Apps.

Comment: They started giving email address in profile API recently, but I am searching for connections :( Still looking for latest updates, don't know if they have email for connections in near future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like apps now have access to the email field, as described here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#email

Note that I haven't used this myself. I was just investigating it because I was spammed by an app used by one of my contacts. If you want to disable this "feature", just click on "Turn on/off data sharing with 3rd party applications" in the "Groups, Companies & Applications" section of the Privacy settings and then untick the box.

Comment: I don't think this has changed - the doc you link to is talking about asking for the authenticating user's email (thus asking for the r_emailaddress permission). Testing the following against the API still returns nothing for email: `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,email-address)`

Comment: Are you sure you've got the r_emailaddress permission? https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/authorization-permission-breaks-authorizetrue-option